# Algorithm for evaluation of spin-weighted spherical harmonics

Tags: quadrature, spherical-harmonics

Is there an algorithm to evaluate spin-weighted spherical harmonics (swSH) at arbitrary points on the sphere? In particular I am looking for, e.g. a recursion relation to evaluate the "spin weighted Legendre functions" ${}_sP^m_l$, which satisfy the follow Sturm-Liouville equation

$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\left(1-x^2\right)\frac{d{}_sP^m_l(x)}{dx}\right)+\left(s-\frac{(m-sx)^2}{1-x^2}\right){}_sP^m_l(x)=-(l-s)(l+s+1){}_sP^m_l(x)
$

over the interval $x\in[-1,1]$.
Classic papers on swSH inclde [this](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1705135) and [this](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/abs/10.1098/rspa.1977.0187) (note I took the above equation from 2.5 of [this](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/abs/10.1098/rspa.1977.0187) paper substituting $x\equiv-\mathrm{cos}\vartheta$). In particular, I'd like to evaluate integrals such as

$ 
\int_{-1}^1dx {}_sP^m_l(x)f(x)
$

(where f is some function I do know how to evaluate) using [Gaussian quadrature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature).

For context: there exist algorithms to compute discrete spherical harmonic transforms, which require the evaluation of the associated Legendre functions (note $P^m_l={}_0P^m_l$). Is there something similar for swSH?

Comment: welcome to SciComp. It would help if you would provide the exact function in the question body (not only a link to a paper). For the quadrature: are it only these functions you need to integrate or are they part of the integrand (since you speak about an associated integral transform). Again, a bit more information (equations?) in the body of the question would help.

Comment: I've edited my question to include definitions of the swSH and the integrals I'd like to compute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, these spin-weighted spherical harmonic functions are equivalent to the [Generalized Associated Legendre functions](https://dlmf.nist.gov/14.29). In the reference work [Virchenko & Fedotova](https://doi.org/10.1142/4463), you can find recurrence relations in chapter 5, p32. Chapter 15, p. 96, of the same reference discusses integral transforms with the Generalized Associated Legendre functions.